# How can I fade a paragraph out right after it was faded in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my function:

```
function showGeneralWarning(msg) {
    if (getIDQuantity("generalWarning") < 1) { 
        $("#Warnings").append('<p id="generalWarning" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;">' + msg + '</p>');
        $("#generalWarning").fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 100).effect("pulsate", { times: 5 }, 1000);
        $("#generalWarning").fadeOut('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 100).effect("pulsate", { times: 5 }, 1000);
    }
}
```

It fades in perfectly, but it stays there forever (It never fades out and go away).

Comment: Use the _complete_ callback of the `fade` functions to execute animations sequentially

Comment: Use a callback as suggested, or a setTimeout if you want it to be displayed for some time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kinda simple example, hope its what you looking for
    `$('.fadein').hide().fadeIn('slow').delay( 800 ).fadeOut('slow');`
https://jsfiddle.net/3spc9541/

Some more on chaining
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! I'm a beginner on JQuery (Specially animations).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the complete function from fadeIn to fadeOut.
as stated on the link

> complete
>
> Type: Function()
>
> A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

[FadeIn api](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)